# How to render UL list by pipe Angular 4?

Tags: angular

I have the following UL list:

```
 <li class="item" *ngFor="let lang of languages | orderBy: 'def'">{{lang.id}}</li>
```

Where `orderBy` is pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
@Pipe({
  name: 'orderBy'
})
export class OrderBy implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array: any[], orderBy: any) {
    return _.sortBy(array, orderBy)

  }
}
```

The `languages` object is:

```
[ { "id": 1, "code": "fr", "active": true, "def": 0, "hide": false }, { "id": 2, "code": "ru", "active": true, "def": 1, "hide": false } ]
```

As you can see this pipe sorts by property `"def"`. In my case the first element `li` should be `{ "id": 2, "code": "ru", "active": true, "def": 1, "hide": false }`.

But I see that it is not happaned. The template is not rendered.

I checked this:

```
var c  = _.sortBy([ { "id": 1, "code": "fr", "active": true, "def": 0, "hide": false }, { "id": 2, "code": "ru", "active": true, "def": 1, "hide": false } ],"def");
```

It returns me object:

```
{id: 1, code: "fr", active: true, def: 0, hide: false}
{id: 2, code: "ru", active: true, def: 1, hide: false}
```

As you can see element with `def: 1` is not in first place.

Comment: `{ "id": 1, "code": "fr", "active": true, "def": 0, "hide": false }` will be the first object as def is 0 for this and 1 for other

Comment: go to underscore site and paste `_.sortBy([ { "id": 1, "code": "fr", "active": true, "def": 0, "hide": false }, { "id": 2, "code": "ru", "active": true, "def": 1, "hide": false } ],"def")` in console check the results

Comment: and there is, see object. May be it sorsts object, but does not render

Comment: can you paste the resulted object here

Comment: See question again, I posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user [array.reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

```
_.sortBy([ { "id": 1, "code": "fr", "active": true, "def": 0, "hide": false }, { "id": 2, "code": "ru", "active": true, "def": 1, "hide": false } ],"def").reverse()
```